# Xamarin Forms LibVLC Video is not shown in Release configuration

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, libvlc, libvlcsharp

We are developing an Xamarin.Froms App and we got some problems with the video player the flowing code is working fine in debug or more specifically when shred runtime is enabled.

Package:

```
    <PackageReference Include="LibVLCSharp.Forms" Version="3.4.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.7.0.1239" />
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Android Package:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.7.0.1239" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="28.0.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="28.0.0.3" />
```

Code behind for page:

```
using LibVLCSharp.Shared;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace myTrekkaApp.Views
{
    public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Core.Initialize();
            LibVLC libVlc = new LibVLC();
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVlc)
            {
                EnableHardwareDecoding = true,

            };
            mediaPlayer.Media = new Media(libVlc, new Uri("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"));
            MediaPlayerElement.MediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
            MediaPlayerElement.LibVLC = libVlc;
            MediaPlayerElement.IsVisible = true;
            mediaPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.Forms.Shared;assembly=LibVLCSharp.Forms"
             x:Class="myTrekkaApp.Views.TestPage">
    <vlc:MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MediaPlayerElement" />
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The native MediaElement in Xamarin.Forms is available now .You could update the version of XF to latest and check the docs from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement .

Comment: can you share logs please? `new LibVLC("--verbose=2")`

Comment: Is it getting linked out? You might need to [manually preserve it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#preserving-code).

Comment: Can you share logs please? Can you reproduce with the official samples?

Comment: might get linked out but it's been fine up until now so I dont think so

Comment: @mfkl I have the exact same problem with Forms - can you please check my log below?

Answer (score 1):

Using r8 needs a bit more config.

> Create a new file in your Xamarin.Android app root named "r8.cfg".
> In this file properties, set the Build Action to "ProguardConfiguration".
> In this file, add the following lines:

```
-keep class org.videolan.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.videolan.**
```

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/android.md